# Jenkins 2 SonarQube Database Connection Error

Tags: jdbc, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-4.5

I am migrating our projects from our old Jenkins instance to Jenkins 2. I also installed the SonarQube Plugin (plugin version on Jenkins 1.6 is 2.4.4 and on Jenkins 2 the plugin version is 2.5).

I copied the SonarQube config and the Sonar jobs config one-to-one from the old instance to the new one.

My problem:

The new Jenkins has problems with the jdbc connections to the sonar database. Especially if I start concurrent Sonar jobs I get the following error log:

```
Started by user MyUser
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@stash.mycompany.net:7999/tcb/com.mycompany.myproduct.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@stash.mycompany.net:7999/tcb/com.mycompany.myproduct.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@stash.mycompany.net:7999/tcb/com.mycompany.myproduct.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision a98a268436cb0e2d5c0b3c0f4b68bc08caf41732 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f a98a268436cb0e2d5c0b3c0f4b68bc08caf41732
 > git rev-list a98a268436cb0e2d5c0b3c0f4b68bc08caf41732 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 41874
[com.mycompany.myproduct.domain] $ java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3_3_9/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3_3_9/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3_3_9 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.62.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar 41874
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/pom.xml clean source:jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in http://artifactory.mycompany.net/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building My Product - domain module 0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in http://artifactory.mycompany.net/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ com.mycompany.myproduct.domain ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (default-cli) > generate-sources @ com.mycompany.myproduct.domain >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) @ com.mycompany.myproduct.domain ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar=destfile=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=com/mycompany/myproduct/domain/**/*Exception.class
[WARNING] Failed to getClass for org.apache.maven.plugins.source.SourceJarMojo
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (default-cli) < generate-sources @ com.mycompany.myproduct.domain <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (default-cli) @ com.mycompany.myproduct.domain ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/target/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain-0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.329 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-16T14:28:33+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/239M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/pom.xml to com.mycompany.myproduct/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain-0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/target/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain-0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.mycompany.myproduct/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain-0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
channel stopped
[myproduct-domain-SONAR] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3_3_9/bin/mvn -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproduct-domain-SONAR/com.mycompany.myproduct.domain/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@tc-ng-db-dev.mycompany.net:1521:ngd ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://tc-services-itdev.mycompany.net:9000 ******** ********
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in http://artifactory.mycompany.net/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building My Product - domain module 0.1.0.32-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in http://artifactory.mycompany.net/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) @ com.mycompany.myproduct.domain ---
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.5.6
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
14:28:37.598 INFO  - Load global referentials...
14:28:37.712 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 116 ms
14:28:37.726 INFO  - User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
14:28:37.733 INFO  - Install plugins
14:28:37.806 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
14:28:37.813 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@tc-ng-db-dev.mycompany.net:1521:ngd
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:26 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-16T14:30:01+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project com.mycompany.myproduct.domain: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project com.mycompany.myproduct.domain: Fail to connect to database
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to connect to database
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:81)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.executeOldVersion(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.executeOldVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:238)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultDatabase.java:103)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:72)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:210)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:321)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:268)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:190)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:107)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:407)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:416)
    ... 62 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube analysis with Maven' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube analysis with Maven' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Could this be occurrend by the different SonarQube plugin versions or by some other parameters? The old jenkins instance can run parallel Sonar jobs without any problem but the new instance seems to have database issues.

Comment: I don't see anything in the log about a DB connection...?

Comment: Connection to database from scanners has been dropped in SonarQube 5.2. As current Long Term Support version is 5.6, I highly recommend to upgrade, it will simplify configuration and fix your issue.

Comment: Ann, scroll to the bottom :-) `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` in Oracle driver.

Comment: If you are looking for a workaround, add a build step to trigger a .sh or .bat file and trigger sonar analysis from there

Comment: We have migrated to sonar 5.6 lts and the sonar tasks are running without problems but now the problem occurs on other tasks with database connection. I seems the the problem was not sonar related but rather related to general database connection issues between jenkins and our oracle db.